Proving that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left (\left|a_{n}\right|+\left|b_{n}\right|\right) <\infty $.

Let $\frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} \cos n x+b_{n} \sin n x$ is absolutely convergent on $E$, where $E$ is a measurable set with $mE>0$. Prove that  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left (\left|a_{n}\right|+\left|b_{n}\right|\right) <\infty $.

$a_{n} \cos n x+b_{n} \sin n x=r_{n} \cos \left (n x+\theta_{n}\right) $, where $r_{n}=\sqrt{a_{n}^{2}+b_{n}^{2}} $.   How to do then?
I know Cantor-Lebesgue theorem: $a_n\cos nx+b_n\sin nx\to 0, x\in E$ implies that $a_n\to 0, b_n\to 0$. But here?
Using Cauchy criteria: $\sum_{k=m}^n |a_k\cos kx+b_k\sin kx|\to 0$, as $m\to\infty$? But it seems not easy (or impossible) to change it to the form $a_n\cos nx+b_n\sin nx$

c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem "Kolmogorov (1923)"

@user I can not visit that website. Could you please give some references, books, papers?

The link in the comment above does not yield this  result. Your result looks quite non-trivial.

For some relevant information, see Section 10.5 in Fourier Series by Edwards

WLOG assume $\int_E \sum_n r_n |\cos(nx+\theta_n)| \lt\infty$ else choose $E$ smaller (with positive measure). Then,
\begin{align*} 
    \int_E \sum_n r_n |\cos(nx+\theta_n)|&= \sum_n r_n\int_E |\cos(nx+\theta_n)|dx \tag{Fubini}
\end{align*}
Now, $ \int_E |\cos(nx+\theta_n)| > c > 0$ where $c$ is independent of $n$ and $\theta_n$ (e.g. the integrand has an antiderivative). Putting this into the above equality, we bound $\sum_n r_n$. Then
$$\sum_n |a_n| \le \sum_n \sqrt{a_n^2+b_n^2} \lt \infty$$

@AnneBauval $E=\cup_n { f(x)< n } \cap E$
