$f_{k} (x) \rightarrow f (x) $, a.e.

Let $f$ and $f_{k} (k \geqslant 1)$ be in $L (\mathbb{R})$ ,  and for any $E, \left\{\int_{E} f_{k} (x)  d x\right\}_{k \geqslant 1}$ is increasing, and the limit is $\int_{E} f (x)  d x $.  Prove that $f_{k} (x)  \rightarrow f (x) $,    a.e.

My attempt. Up to a set of measure zero (the set of Lebesgue points of $f_k,f$, we have
$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{2r}\int_{(x-r,x+r)}f_k(y)dy=f_k(x), \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{2r}\int_{(x-r,x+r)}f(y)dy=f(x)$. But we dot not the the limit is uniform, or else we can change the limit $r\to 0, k\to\infty$?
Any ideas?

$\int_E f_k(x)dx \le \int_E f_{k+1}(x)dx$ for all $E$.  This implies that $f_k \le f_{k+1}$ a.e. for each $k$. So $(f_k)$ increases to some measurable function $g$. Now use the fact that $\int_E g(x)dx=\int_E f(x)dx$ for evry $E$ to see that $g=f$ a.e.
[$f_k-f_1$ is non-negative and increases to $g-f_1$. Montone Convergence Theorem shows that $\int_E (g-f_1) =\lim \int_E (f_k-f_1)$ so $g-f_1$ is integrable and so is $g$. Further, $\int_E g=\lim \int_E f_k=\int_E f$ ].

Thank you . Using Levi, we do not need to prove $g$ is L integrable... could you consider the following problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4891052/proving-that-sum-n-1-infty-left-lefta-n-right-leftb-n-right-ri
